# How to get 'this' on element returned from react render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, this

I have react class. This class in it's render method returns multiple HTML elements. On some of this elements I need to use function that will use 'this' of this element, not whole class.

```js
    // imports

class App extends Components {

  render() {
  const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  const newArr = arr.map((val) => {
          return <li id={IdFactory.register(val, getPath(THIS_LI))} key={val}>{val}</li>
          })
  return (
      <ul>{newArr}</ul>
    )
  }
}
```

IdFactory.register takes a string and path to this element. Any idea how I can distinguish this element for the function?

Answer (score 1):

[image: This]

When you use arrow function it will not create its this context

Tip: If you ever want to find the context of this you can console.log it where you want to find

```
console.log(this)//Put where you want to find.
```

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for. I work a little bit around this topic, and it's starts to grow to the point it looses it's usefulness. Thanks for the input thou.